# How to use awk/sed to reformat this text

Tags: awk, sed

everyone. I have a text file like this:

```
1
question1
answer1
2
question2
answer2
3
question3
answer3
<etc>
```

I've read (and unsuccessfully tried) many different ways using `awk`. I'm not a programmer, so `awk` is difficult to understand.

There are so many of you who are experts in `awk`, so I'm hoping that you will show me the correct command to do this.

Thank you for your help!

I would like to eliminate the numbered lines (1st, 4th, 7th, etc.) then put a comma between the questions and answers so the resulting text file looks like:

```
question1, answer1
question2, answer2
question3, answer3
<etc>
```

Comment: `awk 'NR%3-1{q=$0; getline; a=$0; print q,a}' OFS=', ' file`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk '{n=NR%3} n!=1{printf "%s%s", $0, (n?", ":ORS)}' file
question1, answer1
question2, answer2
question3, answer3
```

Comment: smart, elegant and concise. I learned a trick to control the conditional `ORS` output.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed. Delete every third line starting from first line (`1~3d`), append the next line of input into sed's the pattern space (`N`) and replace the now contained newline in sed's pattern space (`s/\n/, /`).

```
sed '1~3d; N; s/\n/, /' file
```

Output:

```
question1, answer1
question2, answer2
question3, answer3
```

Comment: That's pretty darn slick as well.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n 'n;N;s/\n/, /p' file
```

Sed by default will print every line that it processes, however you can switch this off by using the `-n` option and now sed will only print when we wish it.

The `n` command normally prints the current line and replaces it with the next, but as we have asked it to only print on demand it effectively loses the current line.

The `N` command appends the next line to the current line. As sed normally strips off any newlines before processing a line it first appends a newline `\n` to the current line then appends the next.

The `s/\n/, /p` command substitutes this newline with a `,` followed by a space. The `p` flag at the end of the substitution command prints whatever is in the current line if the substitution was successful. As we have constructed the current line to have a newline in it (`N`) we know this will always happen.

To summarise, the commands: deletes the first line, joins the second and third with a newline and then replaces that newline with a comma followed by space and prints the result. Repeat.

A few of alternatives:

```
sed 'N;s/.*\n//;N;s/\n/, /' file

sed 'N;N;s/.*\n\(.*\)\n/\1, /' file

sed -En 'n;N;G;s/(.)(.*)\1$/, \2/' file
```

The last solution is similar to the first but never refers to a newline directly.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
awk '{
    if ($0 ~ /^[0-9]+$/) {
       /* eliminates lines of all numbers */
    } else if (x == "") {
        /* save until next line is available */
        x = $1;
    } else {
        /* print both */
        print x "," $1;
        /* reset flag */
        x = "";
    }
}'
```

It is not the most elegant awk, as it is more procedural than the pattern -> action that it is designed for....

Comment: That's more like I would do it. Then I look to see what Ed or Charles did. Need `", "` to match requested output.

Comment: Mevets, thank you so much for taking the time to help. I will try both of these solutions tonight.